# Bibliography. Book edition not appearing correctly with babelbib

Tags: bibtex, formatting, babel, spanish

I am writting a document in Kile with TexLive using the `babelbib` package (with the spanish language) and it isn't displaying book editions correctly: if in the `edition` field I put on "2" I get as output `spanish2 edición` while according to my code in overleaf, I should be getting a `2a edición` which is the correct formatting (the `a` should be superscripted and underlined).

I am new to BibTex. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's a minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}

\title{Mecánica cuántica relativista}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

Sample text here. Texto en español.

\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

With this in my `bibio.bib` file:

```
@Book{GreinerRQM,
  author =      "Walter Greiner",
  title =       "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics, Wave Equations",
  publisher =   "Springer-Verlag",
  year =        1997,
  edition =     2,
  isbn =        "3-540-61621-7"
}
```

Edit: This is the pdf file generated by the MWE

[image: Output]

This is the beggining of the log file

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) 
    (format=pdflatex 2016.1.22)  24 JAN 2016 21:14
    entering extended mode
    %&-line parsing enabled.
    **test.tex
    (./test.tex
    LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
    Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english,        usenglishmax,         dumylang, noh
    yphenation, spanish, galician, catalan, loaded.
    (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
    Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
    File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    )
    \c@part=\count79
    \c@section=\count80
    \c@subsection=\count81
    \c@subsubsection=\count82
    \c@paragraph=\count83
    \c@subparagraph=\count84
    \c@figure=\count85
    \c@table=\count86
    \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
    \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
    \bibindent=\dimen102
    )
    (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
    Package: babel 2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package

    (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/spanish.ldf
    Language: spanish.ldf 2009/01/02 v5.0h Spanish support from the babel system
```

Comment: Might be nice to give people a short document they can compile that shows the problem.  (We call it a minimal working example, or MWE for short.)

Comment: Yes, sorry. Added it now.

Comment: You said you are new, maybe start with the more modern alternative of `biblatex` and `biber`. Great for reports and thesis, but many journals haven't updated yet, so not a great idea for journal submision.

Comment: I took the liberty to add the citation so a bibliography is printed and the MWE is of any use. Please test the example, what do you get? Please show the first ten lines of the log file.

Comment: With the example I get “2ª edición”

Comment: Edited post to post log file and output.

Comment: @egreg I posted my output.

Comment: I'm afraid you have a too old TeX distribution.

Comment: Agreeing with egreg, with a current version of TeXlive, all is fine.

Comment: There are some remarks in the dtx that arround 2009 some bugs concerning spanish numerals have been resolved. If you don't want to update your texsystem you could try to update only the spanish.bdf file: Get babelbib.dtx and babelbib.ins from ctan (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/babelbib) but them in some empty folder and compile the babelbib.ins with latex. This will create a lot of files, move the spanish.bdf in the folder of your document.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it solved by updating to current versions of packages